# dev c++ and pointer to string, program hangs

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have the following program made in Dev C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


#define MAX_STRING_LEN 80

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     char* S1 = "cccc";
     char* S2 = "dddd";

     int i, l;

     S2 = S1;
     S1[0] = S1[1] = S1[2] = '*';
     S1[3] = 0;
     printf("S1:\t%s\n",S1);
     printf("S2:\t%s\n",S2);

     system("PAUSE");   
     return 0;
 }
```

but when I run it, the program hangs, actually I am using Dev C++ 4.9.2 and Windows 7
what is the problem?

Comment: `S1[0] = S1[1] = S1[2] = '*';` is trying to modify a string literal, that's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Are you pressing a key at the end?

Comment: yes, I am pressing a key and the program hangs

Comment: So it is what @DanielFischer says, change char* S1 = "cccc"; for this char S1[] = "cccc"; The same with S2.

Comment: Please update tour IDE: http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/?source=directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char* S1 = "cccc";` is actually declaring a `const char*` which points to memory which may be read only.  Writing to these strings in the line

```
S1[0] = S1[1] = S1[2] = '*';
```

gives undefined behaviour and will crash on some platforms.